# SQL query - Selecting distinct values from a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in which i have multiple entries against a FK. I want to find out the value of FK which do not have certain entries e.g
my table has following entries.

```
PK----------------FK-----------------Column entries

1----------------100-----------------ab1
2----------------100-----------------ab2
3----------------100-----------------ab4
4----------------200-----------------ab1
5----------------200-----------------ab2
6----------------200-----------------ab3
7----------------300-----------------ab1
8----------------300-----------------ab2
9----------------300-----------------ab3
10---------------300-----------------ab4
```

Now, from this table i want to filter all those FK which do not have ab3 or ab4 in them. Certainly, i expect distinct values i.e. in this case result would be FK= 100 and 200.
The query which i am using is

```
select distinct(FK) 
from table1 
where column_entries != 'ab3' 
   or column_entries != 'ab4';
```

Certainly, this query is not fetching the desired result.

Comment: What result do you get, and how does it differ from expectations?

Comment: @StilesCrisis Result which i get is FK=100, 200,300. This because the first row of 300 does not have ab3 or ab4.

Comment: Each record satisfy condition because you used `or`; `'ab3' != 'ab3' or 'ab3' != 'ab4'` yields true, as well as `'ab4' != 'ab3' or 'ab4' != 'ab4'`. Use `and` or, to express intent more clearly, `not in` (but comparison list must not contain null).

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović i have tried not in as well, does not bring the result i want i.e FK = 100, 200. It still bring 300 as well.

Comment: Silly me. Ab1 and Ab2 satisfy the condition. You need to select fk's having ab3 or ab4, and exclude them using outer join or not exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try the following :-

```
select distinct fk_col from table1
minus
(select distinct fk_col from table1 where col_entry='ab3'
intersect
select distinct fk_col from table1 where col_entry='ab4')
```

This will show all those FKs which do not have 'ab3' and 'ab4'. i.e. 100 and 200 in your case

Comment: +1, although `distinct` is probably not required. I am not sure but I think it is implied with both `minus` and `intersect`.

Answer (score 1):

The below script may be the solution if I got your question in a right way.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(TableForeignKey)
FROM Test
WHERE TableForeignKey NOT IN (
SELECT T1.TableForeignKey
FROM Test T1 INNER JOIN Test T2 ON T1.TableForeignKey = T2.TableForeignKey
WHERE T1.TableEntry = 'ab3' AND T2.TableEntry = 'ab4')
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/28a6e/7)

Answer (score 0):

You could use GROUP BY with conditional aggregation in HAVING:

```
SELECT FK
FROM table1
GROUP BY FK
HAVING COUNT(CASE column_entries WHEN 'ab3' THEN 1 END) = 0
    OR COUNT(CASE column_entries WHEN 'ab4' THEN 1 END) = 0
;
```

The two conditional aggregates count `'ab3'` and `'ab4'` entries separately. If both end up with results greater than 0, then the corresponding `FK` has both `'ab3'` and `'ab4'` and is thus not returned. If at least one of the counts evaluates to 0, then `FK` is considered satisfying the requirements.